# Disable Keyword Search Suggestion in Joomla Smart Search Module

Tags: search, joomla, module, keyword, finder

I can disable through Smart Search Option.

The search suggestion cannot seem to be disabled when I edit the template file in modules though:
public_html/modules/mod_finder/tmpl

Which file can I update to achieve this?
With search module: 
www.spacebizguide.com

With search component: 
www.spacebizguide.com/component/finder/search?q=search&Itemid=101

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have fixed the error already (possibly it was a caching issue). In any case, you don't need to edit any template file to do so. Just go to `Components` -> `Smart Search`. Click on `Options` on the top right, and then click on "Hide" Next to "Search Suggestions". Do not forget to clear your Joomla (and browser) cache after doing so.